# How do I pivot groups of columns of related data in R?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I have a data set where each observation has 3 variables: time, success (yes or no), damage( yes or no).
but each participant was try 3 times each of the 3 different methods (A,B,C).

But the organization of the data is the worst I could imagine: The data was collected in a way that each row is one participant, but I need each row to be a different observation.

The raw data looks something like this:
[image]

And I want something like this:

[image]

I tried by using pivot longer() but this works only for individual columns, if I do it here I just get repetitions of observations and the overlap and get all scrambled.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data or code as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have a look at the `melt` function from `reshape2` package here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.4/topics/melt.data.frame

Comment: What do you mean by `tidyr::pivot_longer()` works only for individual columns? Maybe an example of code showing what you tried can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should do something like this:

I have created an example data frame similar to yours:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  c(1, 2), 
  c("M", "F"), 
  c(10, 20), 
  c(15, 25),
  c(12, 13), c("yes", "no"), c("yes", "no"),
  c(22, 25), c("yes", "no"), c("no", "yes"),
  c(55, 40), c("no", "yes"), c("yes", "no"),
  c(39, 68), c("yes", "no"), c("yes", "no")
)

colnames(df) <- 
  c("participant", "Gender", "P. info 1", "P. info 2",
    "time A1", "success A1", "demage A1",
    "time A2", "success A2", "demage A2",
    "time B1", "success B1", "demage B1",
    "time B2", "success B2", "demage B2")
```

Some gather/spread manipulations and you receive desired output:

```
df <- df %>%
  gather(key = "Experiment", value = "Value", -c(1:4)) %>% 
  separate(col = "Experiment",
           into = c("Measure", "Method")) %>% 
  separate(col = "Method",
           into = c("Method", "# try"), sep = 1) %>% 
  spread(key = "Measure", value = "Value")
```